# What would be the equivalent of 'haute couture' but for high-end graphic design or visual design?

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire, expressions-idiomatiques

There is *haute couture* and *haute cuisine*, but I'm curious what the expression for 'haute' graphic design or visual design would be?

Comment: Hi Sarah, I'm not sure there is a strict equivalent but maybe a little more context - an example of "haut" graphic design artist, school or brand - would help figuring it out.

Answer (score 1):

La traduction serait probablement rendue par "haut de gamme" (graphisme haut de gamme, ou design graphique haut de gamme).

Answer (score 0):

Le *design*... hmmm... On ne peut quand même pas lui coller un adjectif français, si ? ;-)

Pour ce qui le concerne, j'attendrai l'arrivée de Hight Design ou Hi-Di comme avec la Hi-Fi...
Tiens! Hi-Di ©®aCOSwt 2018... ;-)

On peut trouver au moins dès le début des années 60 l'expression *haut graphisme* utilisée dans des revues d'art contemporain.
Elle n'est cependant pas usuelle.

En fait, c'est vaste ça le graphisme. Les **arts graphiques** regroupent beaucoup de techniques très différentes. Chaque branche doit avoir son appellation précise, je présume.

On pourra ainsi trouver dans la littérature : *haute gravure*, *grande peinture*...

Mais à mon opinion il n'est pas de vrai besoin. On parle de *grande peinture* pour la différencier de la peinture... en bâtiment, de *haute couture* pour la différencier du reprisage des chaussettes, de la *haute cuisine* pour la différencier du snack microondé... ;-) (Bon j'exagère un peu... mais... pas tant que cela.)

Bref pour distinguer l'Art du... tout venant.

Or, si on excepte son acception linguistique hors de propos ici, je n'ai jamais entendu ni lu *graphisme* employé ailleurs que dans le contexte des *arts graphiques*.